# GoogleAuth SignIn on android not obtaining email

Tags: android, vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs3

I am using ionic with vue 3 js and i have this fuction that helps users login with their google account from this package https://github.com/CodetrixStudio/CapacitorGoogleAuth

```
 const logIn = async () => {
      try {
        //const response = await GoogleAuth.signIn();
        GoogleAuth.signIn().then(
          (user) => {
            let email = user.getBasicProfile().getEmail();
            alert(email);
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log(error);
          }
        );
      } catch (e) {
        //
      }
    };
```

I am able to see the dialog that allows users to select an account but when i click on a gmail account of my choice i am not able to get the email address with my code above.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

because not identified by GoogleAuth.signIn()